Unity Remote 5 does not test on the phone, it only shows it
I have to constantly test it on my phone for a project I'm working on about augmented reality. Remote 5 doesn't run the project on my phone, it runs it on the computer and reflects the results on my phone's screen.
-This image is taken from my phone after getting the build.enter image description here
These are the images I took with Remote 5 and Runtime.
enter image description here
As you can see from the fps values, the application runs on the PC and never opens my phone's camera. How can I reverse this? Is there any way to use my phone's camera and itself during runtime?
I don't know of any solutions to try.

Afaik Remote always behaves like that .. it is just for quick prototyping .. you probably have to build and deploy to the phone instead .. alternatively you could use a webcam and attach it to your phone .. a bit clunky but should do the trick

As far as I know, You need to pay for Unity Mars for a decent workflow for mobile AR development. It lets you build a simulated real world environment that you can test features in the editor on. And even then it's not the best.
There's also a good asset I've had success with in the past, but it's been a year or two since I've used it. But... it's $150!
AR Foundation Remote:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/ar-foundation-remote-2-0-201106?srsltid=AfmBOor4zcjzlPf1oVkPCZWCbgJYtLbwh2ylPXQxOZfoa7pZaigfSGmS
In all honestly, I've had better luck buying a used quest3 for development (passthrough mode), then porting it to my phone afterwards once the project is mature enough to warrant the hassle. Just make sure quest supports the feature set you're targeting.
